# Simple column arrangement in Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I try to write more simple such an arrangement of columns depending on the boolean value.

if `false`

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">A</div>
          <div class="col-4">B</div>
          <div class="col-4">C</div>
        </div>
```

[image: First]

But on boolean value if `true`, view be like this:

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">A</div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">B</div>
              <div class="col-12">C</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image: last]

I would like to have a flat structure like and add additional bootstrap classes.. So i want to add some classes if boolean is true:

```
<div class="value ? <boorstrapclasses> : 'col-4'"></div>
<div class="value ? <boorstrapclasses> : 'col-4'"></div>
<div class="value ? <boorstrapclasses> : 'col-4'"></div>
```

Comment: This is react right?

Comment: Nope, Angular 10

Answer (score 0):

So I find solution :)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-{{mode === 'add' ? '6' : '4'}}" style="border: 1px solid green">A</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-{{mode === 'add' ? '6' : '8'}}">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-{{mode === 'add' ? '12' : '6'}}" style="border: 1px solid red">B</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-{{mode === 'add' ? '12' : '6'}}" style="border: 1px solid yellow">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```